# Running docker-compose up, stuck on a "infinite" "creating...[container/image]" php and mysql images

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker, so i don't know if it's a programming mistake or something, one thing i found strange is that in a Mac it worked fine, but running on windows, doesn't.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  db: 
    build: ./backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=demo
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123
  php:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes: 
      - ./frontend:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db
```

Docker file inside ./frontend

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

# Enable mysqli to connect to database
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

# Document root
WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . /var/www/html/
```

Dockerfile inside ./backend

```
FROM mysql:5.7

COPY ./demo.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Console:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating phpsampleapp_db_1  ... done
Creating phpsampleapp_db_1  ...
Creating phpsampleapp_php_1 ...
```

It stays forever like that, i tried a bunch of things. 
I'm using Docker version 17.12.0-ce. And enabled Linux container mode.

I think i don't need the "version" and "services", but anyway.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: Yes but i don't really remember what i did, one thing i remember is that i removed the "services" and "version".

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the fix was simply to restart Docker Desktop. After that all went smoothly